# Force Renew TGT

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, kerberos

In my company we use AD and sleep in that case often the TGT been expire and not renew it.

So it asks again for authentication.

I looked over the network for solution and only found for linux and not for windows.

Is there any option to force renew. Idk like make the tgt ttl to expire in 5 min to force him expire quick and it will renew it?

Answer (score 1):

This question seems a bit strangely worded.  In Microsoft Windows Active Directory, Kerberos TGTs will auto-renew themselves so long as:

1. AD account has not been disabled (or deleted).
2. AD account password has not expired.
3. AD account itself has not expired.
4. AD account doesn't have "User must change password at next logon" flag.

If you want to force-renew your TGT you could:

1. Log off and back on again
2. Run the command klist purge.  At the next access of any Kerberos-protected resource, a new TGT will be obtained, followed by a service ticket (ST) for that resource.